# Preventing Chinese characters in input with JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I need to prevent the user input Chinese character. My code:

```
/^[^\u4E00-\u9FA5]^$/;
```

The result is , the input must be Chinese character input instead of prevent.
Whats wrong with my code??

Comment: post code not an image.

Comment: Note: It's generally preferred that code snippets are posted as text. To format text as a block of code, prefix each line with 4 spaces. The editor also has a `{}` button that can add the prefix to selected text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
chiregex: /^[^\u4E00-\u9FA5]*$/
```

Comment: what is the different between yours and `/^[\u4E00-\u9FA5]+$/`